# Convert pixel data to image in C++

Tags: c++, image, file-io

I have a program that generates an 8-bit image with the following structure:

```
struct int8image
{
  int width;
  int height;
  unsigned char* image;
};
```

Upon dumping the pixel data (int8image.image) to a text file, I got this output:

```
0605 0606 0606 0605 0606 0506 0606 0606
0606 0605 0606 0506 0606 0606 0606 0606
0606 0606 0606 0606 0606 0505 0606 0706
0606 0606 0606 0606 0606 0606 0706 0706
.....
```

How would I go about converting this into a view-able image (the format doesn't matter)?

Comment: You have not presented some critical information:  1) Number of channels (per pixel, such as RGB or B&W, etc);  2) Bits per pixel (e.g. 24 bits, 8 bits, etc.);  3) Endianess (Big Endian or Little Endian).  BTW, images are not part of the C++ language, but platform specific.

Comment: That data does not match that struct! If the width is the first integer, then that is `06050606` and, funnily enough the height is `06060605` and the first line of the image has pixels that are the same brightness as the file size - I think not! Give a link to the whole image and also its dimensions and I will more than likely be able to work it out for you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The data I posted was only the image data (testimage.image), so width and height are not included in this. The height is 1040 and the width is 1392. I uploaded a .txt file with the full data here (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2ev8__yNKEGNFJJZ0s0VG5YSVk/view?usp=sharing)
Please note that the data is different form what I posted above since this is a different image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the image with ImageMagick at the command line. It is installed on most Linux distros and available for OS X (ideally via `homebrew`) and also Windows.

If you want to convert it to a PNG, you can run this:

```
convert -size 1392x1040 -depth 8 image.gray -auto-level image.png
```

[image]

Your image is very low contrast, so I added `-auto-level` to stretch it. Your image is greyscale.

You can also achieve the same processing with the ImageMagick C++ library [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/).

Comment: Woah.. That was simple enough. I tried it and it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Easy when you know how ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use OpenCV. You can convert your structure to a cv::Mat using width and height as dimensions. Then you can use OpenCV functions to view the image or write out a bmp, png, tiff, or jpg fairly easily. Given that you have unsigned char data, I assume it is already 8-bit grayscale so it'd look like this.

```
int8image testData;

// Do stuff in your program so that testData contains an image.

// Define a cv::Mat object with a pointer to the data and the data type set
// as "CV_8U" which means 8-bit unsigned data
cv::Mat image( testData.height, testData.width, CV_8U, testData.image );

// Write the image to a bitmap in the current working directory named 
// "test.bmp". This is just an example of one way you could write it out.
cv::imwrite( "test.bmp", image );
```

Answer (score 0):

A library is most flexible, but if you're looking for quick and dirty, you can write out a simple 54-byte BMP header for RGB24 and assuming your data is gray scale, simply repeat the octet for each of the 3 components of each pixel.  Or if you want to be able to write the image data a bit more directly, write the BMP header for a palletized image, and your pallet is essentially the 256-entry gray scale (000000,010101,020202...ffffff).  Pretty straightforward either way if you look up the BMP header format.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use the [LodePNG library](http://lodev.org/lodepng), it is very easy to setup because it has no dependencies, you can simply put the source files into your project and compile with it. It is very easy to use and allows you to save that data into a loseless PNG image.